# PHP | Как задать параметр в переменную, если он не передан ООП

Tags: php, веб-программирование, ооп

Приветствую, есть код PHP, проблема заключается в том, что при вызове метода `GetInventory()` производится передача параметра, но мне нужно сделать так, что если параметр не передан, присвоить стандартные значения `$this->param`, но у меня это не выходит.

```
    class steam{


        private $Bots_ID = array();
        private $Weapons = array();
        private $param =  array('id','name','quality','market_name');
        private $SteamID = 0;
        private $Link = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/[steamid]/inventory/json/730/2";

        public function __construct($bots_id = array()){
            $this->Bots_ID = $bots_id;
        }

        public function GetInventory($param = $this->param){

            $this->SteamID = 1234567890;
            $this->param = $param;

            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents( preg_replace("/\[steamid\]/i", $this->SteamID, $this->Link) ), true);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['rgInventory']); $i++) {

                $element_name = array_shift($data['rgInventory']);
                $code_item    = $element_name['classid']."_".$element_name['instanceid'];

                $this->Weapons[$i]['id'] = $element_name['id'];
            } 

            return $this->Weapons;
        }

    }










    $steam = new steam();

    $items = $steam->GetInventory();

    print_r($items);

    ?>
```

Comment: `if (!$param) $param = $this->param` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задайте значение переменной `$param` по умолчанию равной `null` и делайте проверку. В случае если `$param` равен `null` используйте `$this->param`.

Пример:

```
...
public function GetInventory($param = null){
    ...
    $this->param = isset($param) ? $param : $this->param;
...
```

или

```
...
public function GetInventory($param = null){
    ...
    if( ! isset($param) ){
        $this->param = $param;
    }
...
```

В версии php 7 и выше можно использовать новый синтаксис. Пример:

```
...
public function GetInventory($param = null){
    ...
    $this->param = $param ?? $this->param;
...
```

Comment: А как же новая фишка php, такая как `$param ?? $this->param`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев В вопросе не указана версия php. Новая "фишка" не будет работать в версии ниже 7.

Comment: Я не критикую, я лишь спрашиваю, было бы интересно увидеть пример такой реализации в номом синтаксисе. Почему нет? Разработка на месте не стоит :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев В случае с `??` нужно использовать `null` вместо `false`. Так что поправил оба предыдущих варианта, что бы было единообразно, и добавил новый.

Comment: Благодарю, я думаю можно просто как-то присвоить при приеме самого параметра, но нет.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
public function GetInventory($param = null){
    if($param === null) {
       $param = $this->param;
    }
...
```